# Selenium IDE sendKey to input element does not trigger event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium

I am using selenium IDE, writing tests for an JQuery based application. I have on previous endeavours used sendKey and type. In the site there is a input box on top in a ul dropdown.

- When a user types a number into the dropdown.
- Clicks outside it.
- The value typed gets reflected to other labels on the site.

In using selenium though:

- focus
- sendKeys
- click

Does not trigger any event in the JS to update labels...

I have also tried using runscript `$('body').click();` to trigger some event but no success.

```
<div class="lblButton optType">
    <label id="lSystem" data-rule="{'id':'b10','value':10}">10</label>
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <ul class="widget">
        <li class="option tagV10" data-rule="{'id':'b10','value':10}">10</li>
        <li class="option tagV20" data-rule="{'id':'b20','value':20}">20</li>
        <li class="option tagV30" data-rule="{'id':'b30','value':30}">30</li>
    </ul>
    <input class="lblButtonIn" type="number" style="background-color: transparent;">123</input>
</div>
```

How do i properly simulate changing the input value and clicking outside the input/dropdown? (I can not share the full js but below is the part I think important:)

```
var parent = field.parent(), label = parent.find('>label');
field.bind( 'blur', function( e ) {
setTimeout( function() {
if ( field.hasClass('invalid') ) {
field.get(0).value = label.text();
field.removeClass('invalid');
}
else {
var v = field.get(0).value, r = '{\'id\':\'b'+v+'\',\'value\':'+v+'}';
label.html( field.get(0).value ).attr('data-rule',r);
}
updateGt(), $('body').click();
}, 20);
```